# How to use Regression Analysis to Identify Correlation

Tags: machine-learning, regression, correlation

I have two variables Price and Distance, and want to find out if there exists a correlation between the two and how statistically significant it is.

I created a linear model in python using least-squares, but don't know how I could derive any measure of correlation from it.

Thanks,

Comment: how about just computing.... correlation? Spearman correlation should do just fine (pearson might be mislead by different scales of your data).

Comment: Yes, wondering how it could be done in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could derive the correlation from regression output, provided we are talking about simple regression with one predictor variable. There are two ways. First, simply take the square root of the R-squared statistic. Of course, since it is R-*squared*, we're not sure if the correlation is positive or negative. So, look at the sign on the beta coefficient. If it's negative, you know the correlation is also negative. Alternatively, you divide the beta coefficient by ratio of standard deviations.

[image: formula]

So,

[image: formula]

You can then convert r to a t-statistic to determine if it is significant.

Comment: In here is Y the predicted value for input X_i?

Comment: No Y is the original response variable. Note that this is for simple linear regression.

Answer (score -1):

In order to find the correlation between two variables, the best way is to do a scatter plot for the two variables. A scatter plot can give you an intuition of how the variables are correlated.
      [image: Scatter plot]

There is another way to check the correlation by plotting a heatmap using seaborn library. A seaborn heatmap looks like this with the correlation values for different variables.

[image]